# MPDF - fseek error

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf-generation, mpdf

I am trying to merge files together into one pdf. The files could be pdf, png or jpg files. Images work fine, its only when I try to export the pdf files that I get an error. The error is show below.

```
Message: fseek(): stream does not support seeking
```

I thought I found a solution from various forums relating to the path of the file. However, if I change the path it shows this error

```
mPDF error: Cannot open http://192.168.2.35/marine/certificate_files/a025ad3d40b22ac760ba7af7b6bb259d.pdf
```

My controller code is below

```
include('mpdf/mpdf.php');
    $mpdf=new mPDF();
    $mpdf->SetImportUse();
    $mpdf->SetFooter($personnel_data->firstname . ' ' . $personnel_data->lastname . '|{PAGENO}|' . $personnel_data->ID_number );

    foreach($certificate_data as $certificates)
    {
        $certificate_extension['type'] = explode('.',$certificates->certificate_name);

        if($certificate_extension['type'][1]==='pdf')
        {
            $pagecount = @$mpdf->SetSourceFile('http://192.168.2.35/marine/certificate_files/' . $certificates->certificate_name);
            $tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($pagecount);
            $mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
            $mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak>');
        }
        if($certificate_extension['type'][1]!=='pdf')
        {
            $mpdf->WriteHTML('<p><img src="' . $this->config->base_url('assets/images/header-logo.png') . ' "></p>');
            $mpdf->WriteHTML('<style>body {font-family: arial;}</style>');
            $mpdf->WriteHTML('<p> ' . $certificates->certificate . ' - ' .  $certificates->expiry_dates . '</p>');
            $mpdf->WriteHTML('<p><img src="' . $this->config->base_url('certificate_files/' . $certificates->certificate_name) . ' "></p>');
            $mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak>');
        }
        else
        {
            $mpdf->WriteHTML('');
        }
    }

    $mpdf->Output();
    exit;
```

If any help or guidance could slide my way form anyone I would be forever grateful! Thanks!

Comment: which PDF-Version is your source file? I had problems with pdfs >= 1.6 before...

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know mpdf is based on fpdf (fpdi)... from the FPDI website: http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi-pdf-parser/

> By default FPDI can "only" handle PDF documents up to PDF version 1.4.
>   Beginning with PDF version 1.5 there were new compression features
>   introduced which involve internal structure changes how a PDF document
>   can be created.

Please try it with an PDF Version <= 1.4 for testing...

in my case it was the reason and I bought a developer license for the commercial pfdi pdf parser for 100€